# R: how to multiply each value with the next one over a row or column?

Tags: r, multiplication

I could of course use a loop for this, but given my large data matrix this will most likely take forever. I have a data matrix with the dimensions 5000x250. The 5000 values for each subject lie around 1. Now I want to multiply over all values of each column (j), like this:

```
x[1,j]*x[2,j]*x[3,j]...*x[5000,j]
```

Could anybody please tell me how to do this in a computationally efficient way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the apply function to make it the prod in each row or each column:

```
data <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
apply(data, 1, prod) #1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns
##[1] 4.780159e+14 1.242689e+15 2.394833e+15 4.060163e+15 6.393839e+15
##[6] 9.585619e+15 1.386570e+16 1.951127e+16 2.685395e+16 3.628800e+16
 #You get a vector with the result of multiply each element of each row
```

Answer (score 4):

have a look at `?prod`

```
data <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
data
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##  [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
##  [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
##  [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
##  [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
##  [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
##  [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
##  [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
##  [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
##  [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
## [10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

prod(data[, 2])
## [1] 670442572800
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(parse(text=paste(x[,j], collapse="*")))
```